# Applescript to set non focus tab in safari

Tags: safari, applescript

I made a script to find an tab based on it's URL and set a new URL (the tab is not focused)

```
tell application "Safari"
    set topWindows to every window whose name is not ""
    set numWindows to the number of topWindows
    set didFind to false
    set targetUrl to "https://www.apple.com"

    repeat with x from 1 to numWindows
        set numTabs to the number of tabs in window x
        repeat with y from 1 to numTabs
            set tabUrl to the URL of tab y of window x
            if tabUrl contains targetUrl then
                set didFind to true
                tell window x to set current tab to tab y
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat

end tell

set myLink to "https://www.apple.fr"


tell application "Safari"
    tell front window
        set URL of tab y to myLink
    end tell
end tell
```

The correct tab is found, the index is found, but it's seems to always open the URL in a the latest tab instead of the existing tab

how can I fix this?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/333845/263848

Comment: Couple suggestions:  1. Try to use good variable names. Instead of x, y, etc. use actual names.  2. When using indexed loops (` x from 1 to numWindows`) traditionally the the variable `i` is used to represent the "**i**ndex".  3. Unless you need to change the content of the the array you are iterating through or need to limit it some how, use for each loops. This eliminates the use of the index. So instead of `repeat with x from 1 to the number of theWindows` use `repeat with aWindow in theWindows`.  4. Use functions

Comment: @JBis By "functions", do you in fact mean "handlers" ?

Answer (score 2):

```
set targetUrl to "https://www.apple.com"
use currentApp : application "Safari"
set _T to a reference to (every tab of every window of currentApp whose ¬
    URL contains targetUrl)

if (count _T) > 0 then return viewTab(_T)
end

to viewTab(aURL)
    set [aURL] to aURL
    set W to the first window of currentApp whose tabs contains aURL

    set current tab of W to aURL
    activate currentApp
    set the index of W to 1
end viewTab
```

[Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/333845/263848)

Comment: I don't manage to set the second URL using your script though, the second URL should be referenced with aURL right?

Comment: @Kevin viewTab is a function that accepts a URL as a parameter/argument. Any URL passed to it will make the tab with that URL active. You have a couple issues with your script which I'll address in a later comment.

Comment: @JBis You said: _"viewTab is a function that accepts a URL as a parameter/argument"_, which isn't correct from what I'm seeing, as **a)** you send as its parameter a reference to a collection of collections of `tabs`, namely `_T`; and **b)** if you did send a simple URL as the parameter, `set current tab of W to aURL` would throw an error, as it is expecting a `tab` object.

Comment: @CJK Ah, i see what it's doing now. May i ask why you pass by reference instead of value?

Comment: In general situations, it's often much faster for AppleScript to enumerate collections and iterate through them by reference, particularly when large. It also allows you to filter collections on the fly, instead of having to filter them at the point of declaration. But in the context specific to this answer, the first line of the handler, `set [aURL] to aURL` picks out the first _viable_ element from a referenced collection.  If it were passed by value and the collection was something like `{{}, {}, {}, {tab id n of...}, {...}, ...}`, it would pick out `{}` instead.

Comment: @CJK Interesting...Do you use any other languages or primarily AppleScript?

Comment: @JBis I used to program a lot in PHP a long time ago, but have since forgotten most of it.  Now, I tend to use in no particular order AppleScript, JavaScript, shell (bash and fish), and Objective-C (mostly in the form of AppleScriptObjC because I hate _XCode_).  I'm wanting to learn Swift, do more with Haskell, and maybe learn Lua as well.  I did quite a bit of Lisp in the first year of my degree, which was a 25% Computer Science degree.  But I am a lot more confident sharing my knowledge of AppleScript than other languages, as other people are better than I at, e.g. JavaScript or ObjC.

Comment: (Which just made is sound like other people aren't better than I at AppleScript, which I wouldn't assume is remotely true. There are many older answers of mine on SO that I would now implement differently, so I'm still learning and (hopefully) getting better all the time.)

Comment: @CJK Ah, knew there had to be some background in other languages. 99% of people who use AppleScript don't have deeper understanding of anything relating to computer science, because most who do wouldn't use AppleScript. Many will know the basic loops, functions, conditionals, etc. But passing by references vs value is more of an "advanced" topic in my mind. Also the way you code is...well...good.

Comment: Sadly apple script is dyeing though. None of the new apps really support it well. Messages handler removed. etc.

Comment: Needless use of `end` after `if (count _T) > 0 then return viewTab(_T)`. You only need `end` in this case if `return viewTab(_T)` is not on the same line as `if (count _T) > 0 then`.